# How do I find specific planner configuration options?

Tags: ros, ompl-planning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically, I'd like to re-ask [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/845/where-is-the-documentation-on-ompl_ros_interface).

I would like to run some benchmarking tests using several of the planners available in ompl.  I would also like to be able to experiment with different configuration options for those planners.  But in order to populate ompl_planning.yaml, I need to know what those options are named, and presumably this will vary by planner type.  How do I find this out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11801/how-do-i-find-specific-planner-configuration-options?/) by [tom temple](https://answers.ros.org/users/900/tom-temple/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-11-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently all the options are not filled in the yaml file itself but you can look into the src/ompl_ros_planning_group.cpp file to find which planners and options are supported. I will try and get out a better yaml file or more information on the Wiki to help with that.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1